# Apply templates not working as desired

Tags: xslt

Given the following xml inputs:
file1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<File1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <code code="file1_code" displayName="file1_display" codeSystem="file1_cs" codeSystemName="file1_csn"/>

    <title>Title of file1</title>   
    <component typeCode="COMP">
        <structuredBody classCode="DOCBODY">
            <component typeCode="COMP">
                <section>
                    <templateId root="someRoot_file1" assigningAuthorityName="someAuhthority_file1"/>
                    <code code="file1-sec1_code" displayName="file1_sec1_display" codeSystem="file1_sec1_cs" codeSystemName="file1_sec1_csn"/>
                    <title>Tile of sec 1 from file1</title>
                    <text>
                        <content styleCode="Italics">
                            Text of sec 1 from file1
                        </content>
                    </text>             
                    <entry> file 1 sec 1                    
                    </entry>
                </section>
            </component>
            <component typeCode="COMP">
                <section classCode="DOCSECT">                   
                    <code code="file1_sec2_code" codeSystem="file2_sec2_cs" displayName="file2_sec2_display" codeSystemName="file2_sec2_csn"/>
                    <title>Tile from sec 2 file 1</title>
                    <text>
                        <content styleCode="Italics">
                            Text from file1 sec 2
                        </content>
                    </text>
                    <entry typeCode="test"> file2 sec 2
                    </entry>
                </section>
            </component>
        </structuredBody>
    </component>
</File1>
```

file2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
<title value="Title of file2"/>
    <text>
        <status value="generated"/>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>File 2 Text</p>          
        </div>
    </text>
    <section>
        <code>
            <coding>
                <system value="sec 1 file2 sys"/>
                <code value="sec 1 file 2 code"/>
                <display value="sec 1 file 2 display"/>
            </coding>
        </code>
        <title>Title of sec 1 file2</title>
        <text>
            <content styleCode="Italics">Section 1 Text
            </content>
        </text>         
        <entry>
            <someEntry>                 
            </someEntry>
        </entry>
    </section>
    <section>
        <code>
            <coding>
                <system value="sec 2 file2 sys"/>
                <code value="sec 2 file 2 code"/>
                <display value="sec 2 file 2 display"/>
            </coding>
        </code>
        <title>Title of sec 2 file2</title>
        <text>
            <content styleCode="Italics">Section 2 file2 Text
            </content>
        </text>         
        <entry>
            <someEntry> entry sec 2 file 2              
            </someEntry>
        </entry>
    </section>

</A>
```

and the following xslt:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

        <xsl:variable name="input" select="/" />

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <Bundle>
                <id value="test"/>          
                <type value="document"/>
                <entry>             
                    <resource>                  
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file2.xml')/*"/>             
                    </resource> 
                </entry>
            </Bundle>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template match="text">
            <text>
                <status value="generated"/>
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <p>This is the text from the stylesheet </p>                
                </div>
            </text>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="title">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$input/File1/title"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="section[1]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$input/File1/component/structuredBody/component/section"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="section[2]"/>      

        <xsl:template match="File1/title">
            <title>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </title>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match = "File1/component/structuredBody/component/section">       
            <section>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </section>
        </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bundle>
    <id value="test"/>
    <type value="document"/>
    <entry>
        <resource>
            <A>
                <title value="Title of file1"/>
                <text>
                    <status value="generated"/>
                    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <p>This is the text from the stylesheet </p>
                    </div>
                </text>
                <section>
                    <templateId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" root="someRoot_file1" assigningAuthorityName="someAuhthority_file1"/>
                    <code xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" code="file1-sec1_code" displayName="file1_sec1_display" codeSystem="file1_sec1_cs" codeSystemName="file1_sec1_csn"/>
                    <title value="Title of file1"/>
                    <text>
                        <status value="generated"/>
                        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                            <p>This is the text from the stylesheet </p>
                        </div>
                    </text>
                    <entry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <code xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" code="file1_sec2_code" codeSystem="file2_sec2_cs" displayName="file2_sec2_display" codeSystemName="file2_sec2_csn"/>
                    <title value="Title of file1"/>
                    <text>
                        <status value="generated"/>
                        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                            <p>This is the text from the stylesheet </p>
                        </div>
                    </text>
                    <entry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" typeCode="test"/>
                </section>
            </A>
        </resource>
    </entry>
</Bundle>
```

And this is the expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bundle>
    <id value="test"/>
    <type value="document"/>
    <entry>
        <resource>
            <A>
                <title value="Title of file1"/>
                <text>
                    <status value="generated"/>
                    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <p>This is the text from the stylesheet </p>
                    </div>
                </text>             
                <section>
                    <templateId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" root="someRoot_file1" assigningAuthorityName="someAuhthority_file1"/>
                    <code xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" code="file1-sec1_code" displayName="file1_sec1_display" codeSystem="file1_sec1_cs" codeSystemName="file1_sec1_csn"/>
                    <title>Tile of sec 1 from file1</title>
                    <text>
                        <content styleCode="Italics">
                            Text of sec 1 from file1
                        </content>
                    </text>             
                    <entry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <code xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" code="file1_sec2_code" codeSystem="file2_sec2_cs" displayName="file2_sec2_display" codeSystemName="file2_sec2_csn"/>
                    <title>Tile from sec 2 file 1</title>
                        <text>
                            <content styleCode="Italics">
                                Text from file1 sec 2
                            </content>
                        </text>
                    <entry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" typeCode="test"/>
                </section>
            </A>
        </resource>
    </entry>
</Bundle>
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why is the title in the section elements coming from the main title (i.e. `File1/title`) when the apply templates is within `File1/component/structuredBody/component/section`? I was expecting that the title of the section will be output, which is what is desired. Even more confusing is that it does indeed output the elements in the section like code, entry and so on but title and text (see q2 below) seems to be treated differently and I can't for the life of me understand why.
2. Same with text. Why is the text for section not being output?

Here is my presumably false understanding of the process:

We start with the  `<xsl:template match="/">` and create elements Bundle, id etc. and then using `<xsl:apply-templates select="document('file2.xml')/*"/>` we match the top element of file2 (A) and since we don't have a template matching it explicitly, the identity template is called, copies it and process its child elements, which are text, title and section. For each of these child elements, it looks for a matching template. it finds them and matches them.

For element section however, it matches only the first section element because of `<xsl:template match="section[1]">` and then because of `<xsl:apply-templates select="$input/File1/component/structuredBody/component/section"/>` in the template, it looks for a template matching children of section in FIle1, which are code, text, title and templateId. It finds no such explicitly defined template, so calls the identity templates for them, copies and processes them till the end. At least that is my understanding of it.

Comment: IMHO, your XSLT needs a rewrite. I could barely understand what it does, but certainly not what is it *meant* to do.

Comment: I am trying to map some elements from file1 and file2. Some of the elements in file1 are identical to those in file2, so will just be copied. Others need changing and so on. Same with file1. Some of its elements will be copied as they are and will remain the same. Others however may need modification and or being replaces with some parts/section of file2.

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't mean much to me. What could help here is seeing the expected output. And I would also start with something simpler, then add more complexity as you go.

Comment: Removed the text() node from the xslt file since it only add to confusion and is not that relevant anyway as I only added it because I was getting some white spaces in the output. I have added the expected output.

Comment: Added my understanding of how the xslt apply works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the title in the section elements coming from the main title

Because any time the processor is instructed to apply templates to a `title`, it looks for the best-matching template to apply, and finds this:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$input/File1/title"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This changes the context to the `title` in File1.xml, and the best-matching template for this one is:

```
<xsl:template match="File1/title">
    <title>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </title>
</xsl:template>
```

and that is the result you see.

---

> Same with text. Why is the text for section not being output?

***-- edited in response to the following clarification: --***

> When I say text I am talking about text elements only.

The original `text` element (child of `section` in File1.xml) is not being output because you have a specific template matching it and outputting something else instead:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <text>
        <status value="generated"/>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>This is the text from the stylesheet </p>                
        </div>
    </text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't get it. The apply template is being called from within `"File1/component/structuredBody/component/section"`. And if the best match in this case is `match=title`, the same should be the case for `match=code` but for code (I didn't add the code template but you can just add a code and test and you will see what I mean) but for code it ignores that and outputs the code within the section as desired. 

That was also my suspicion in the beginning, that it is due to `<xsl:template match="text()"/>` but that is not the case. You can try to comment it and see, result is the same.

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstand how the [XSLT processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model) works. I could explain each case and case in detail, but that would be both time-consuming and pointless - because, as I said earlier, IMHO you need to restructure the whole thing.

Comment: When you say "text" I'm not sure if you're talking about text nodes, or about element nodes named "text". But either way, the stylesheet is doing exactly what you have asked it to do, and it's difficult to understand why you would expect it to do anything different. You've clearly mis-understood something about the language, but it's not clear exactly what your misunderstanding is

Comment: When I say text I am talking about text elements only. Yeah it seems I have misunderstood something about how apply template works or something. My understanding of apply was and it seems to be close to what is also refered in the link that Michael.hor257k gave is that apply templates wiiout select processes children nodes of current node, in this case the children of element section in file1 but it seems that is not the case for some elements like text and title though it is for the rest.

Comment: I *think* the part that you don't understand is that `xsl:apply-templates` changes the context. In the above case, you may be in the context of `title` in File2 - but you call for templates to be applied to `"$input/File1/title"`. That effectively redirects you to the `title` in File1.

Comment: Yeah, that is probably the case. Seem my response below.

Answer (score 0):

@ michael.hor257k and @Michael Kay yeah, that was definitely the case, that I misunderstood how `xsl:apply-templates` works with regards to context . I thought because I called the `xsl:apply-templates` from within `xsl:template match = "$input/File1/component/structuredBody/component/section">` that it will only look for match templates that match the children of section. In other words, I thought it will look for templates like `“<xsl:template match=”File1/component/structuredBody/component/section/title">` but that is clearly not the case.

`xsl:apply-templates` simply looks for the children and then looks for a match template regardless of the context from which they were called. So, it will look for title or text template that matches and if it finds them, it will match them.

The easiest solution I could find that seems to solve the problem is to add a path to the title and text templates. In other words, instead of just `<xsl:template match="text">` I should have `<xsl:template match="A/text">`. Same for title. This way, the `xsl:apply-templates` will not apply `<xsl:template match="A/text">` as the title in section is not a child of A. So given that no matching explicit template is defined, the identity template will be applied and will output the title of section as desired.

Comment: Now, it would be nice if I could get rid of those namespaces in the output

Comment: IMHO, this does not provide an answer to your question. As for the namespaces, I suggest you post another question - preferably with a simpler example.